# Assigning a constant with mutate_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to set all values in each of several columns to `NA`. Normally, if I would like to modify several columns using the same algorithm I would use `mutate_each` from dplyr. From an algorithmic standpoint, the function "x maps to null" seems perfectly well-defined, so I tried to do that. However, I got an error: `Error in make_call(x$expr, args) : Unknown inputs`.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
sample <- data.frame(a = seq(1, 3), b = seq(5, 7))

sample %>% mutate(a = 1, b = 1)           # Works fine
sample %>% mutate_each(funs(. - 1), a, b) # Works fine
sample %>% mutate_each(funs(1), a, b)     # Blows up
sample %>% mutate_each(funs(NA), a, b)    # Blows up
```

I also tried explicitly defining a function, eg

```
mutate_each(funs(function(x) {NA}), Address, City, State, Zip)
```

This leads to a different error: `Error: Unsupported type CLOSXP for column "a"`. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: duct-tape: `sample %>% mutate_each(funs(.*0 + NA), a, b)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico indeed, this workaround is also fine: `funs(.*0+1)` and `funs(.+NA)`. Note: if there are NAs in the data, it won't turn them into ones (see my post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just `1` is not a function name (see the help page of mutate_each). You have to use brackets; this will work:

```
sample %>% mutate_each(funs({1}), a, b) 
####   a b
#### 1 1 1
#### 2 1 1
#### 3 1 1
sample %>% mutate_each(funs({NA}), a, b)
####   a  b
#### 1 NA NA
#### 2 NA NA
#### 3 NA NA
```

This will turn everything to NA or ones. But what if you have NAs in your data.frame and you want to keep them as they are? In that case, the solution suggested by @MichaelChirico (in the comments) works.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression (c/o "Advanced R" by Wickham) that everything is a function in R. I guess "nearly everything" is the right idea.

Comment: makes sense -- R is looking for a function named `1` and comes up short... snazzy that there's a simple solution (`{}`), though perhaps there could be a better error message.